# Finding syntax-error in a file that have a custom format using RexEx

Tags: php, regex, syntax-error, text-processing

I have a big text file (144000 line) that have a custom format like following:

```
xxx
XXXfield1XXX
value1
xxx
xxx
XXXfield2XXX
value2
xxx
xxx
XXXfield3XXX
value3
xxx
```

But there is a syntax-error (perhaps more) in the file (Because total line number of file is not dividable to four)

How can I find the line number of error using just  **RegExp**?

Comment: Detecting is easy .. automatically fixing is hard ....  If you only want to detect let me know

Comment: I want know the place of error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detecting Error is easy .. Imagine

log.txt

```
xxx
XXXfield1XXX
value1
xxx
xxx
XXXfield2XXX <----- Note that this field has no value 
xxx
xxx
XXXfield3XXX
value3
xxx
value3
xxx
```

Simple Scanner

```
$fileSource = "log.txt";
$tagRow = "xxx";
$tagField = "XXX";

$rh = fopen($fileSource, 'rb');
if (!$rh) {
    trigger_error("Can't Start File Resource");
}
echo "<pre>";
$i = 0;
while ( ! feof($rh) ) {
    $l = trim(fgets($rh));
    if ((($i % 4) == 0 || ($i % 4) == 3) && $l != $tagRow) {
        echo "Row tag error line $i \n";
        break;
    }

    if (($i % 4) == 1 && strpos($l, $tagField) !== 0) {
        echo "Missing Field tag line $i  \n";
        break;
    }

    if (($i % 4) == 2 && (strpos($l, $tagRow) === 0 || strpos($l, $tagRow) === 0)) {
        echo "Fixed Missing Value line $i \n";
        break;
    }
    $i ++;
}
fclose($rh);
```

Output

```
  Fixed Missing Value line 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a program to read the file, one line at a time, and parse it.  If a line isn't consistent with the format, then report the error and exit.

As you read each line, keep track of the line number.  Base your tests on the line number using the `%` operator and a switch statement.

```
switch ($linecount % 4) {
    case 0:
        $error = (some condition that evaluates the line);
        break;
    case 1:
        $error = (some condition that evaluates the line);
        break;
    case 2:
        $error = (some condition that evaluates the line);
        break;
    case 3:
        $error = (some condition that evaluates the line);
        break;
}
if ($error) {
    echo 'Error on line ' . $linenum . ': ' . $line;
    exit;
}
```